# Decimal values in visual studio report

Tags: c#, report

I have a problem with decimal values in visual studio report (rdlc)
the values stored in the database are in decimal format ( real number )

[image: some data stored in the database]

but when i open the report it seems like the values are rounded.
I tried to format the field to D2 ( decimal with two places ) but no hope

[image: rdlc Report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, i just figured out how to do it.
The problem was , the datatype of that field in the report's dataset was Int32 so i changed it to Double and it worked just fine.
From .xsd file which contains the dataSet and DataAdapter i chose the field and change its datatype.
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hJOt.png)

Answer (score 0):

it is easy brother change the field datatype from intger to double
it will work fine
good luck